# Weighted graph database recommedations

Tags: graph-databases

What would be a good database for fast search of the k shortest paths in a weighted graph?  Keyword search for nodes would be a plus, but that could be done externally.  The main concern is efficiently searching for the best paths between nodes.

Answer (score 1):

This post is nearly four years old and the world of graph databases has come a long way since this question was posted. Several products could probably perform this search efficiently. I will provide an example of how Objectivity/DB could be used to perform this search.

Objectivity/DB is a schema-based object/graph database with a complete set of graph navigational query capabilities. It has its own DO Query Language.

Let's build a graph from this image of towns and roads:

[image: Town and road node edge graph]

Let's create our schema as follows:

```
UPDATE SCHEMA { 
    CREATE CLASS Town  {
        name        : STRING,               
        from        : List { Element: 
                        Reference { EdgeClass: Road, EdgeAttribute: from }, 
                        CollectionTypeName: TreeListOfReferences 
                    },
        to          : List { Element: 
                        Reference { EdgeClass: Road, EdgeAttribute: to }, 
                        CollectionTypeName: TreeListOfReferences 
                    }       
    }
        
    CREATE CLASS Road {
        distance    : INTEGER { Storage: B32 }, 
        from        : Reference { referenced: Town, Inverse: to },
        to          : Reference { referenced: Town, Inverse: from }
    }
};
```

And then we can load our data to match the picture above:

```
let townA = create Town { name: "TownA" };
let townB = create Town { name: "TownB" };
let townC = create Town { name: "TownC" };
let townD = create Town { name: "TownD" };
let townE = create Town { name: "TownE" };
let townF = create Town { name: "TownF" };
let townG = create Town { name: "TownG" };
let townH = create Town { name: "TownH" };

let roadAB = create Road { distance: 4, from: $townA, to: $townB };
let roadBC = create Road { distance: 5, from: $townB, to: $townC };
let roadCH = create Road { distance: 10, from: $townC, to: $townH };
let roadAD = create Road { distance: 3, from: $townA, to: $townD };
let roadDC = create Road { distance: 6, from: $townD, to: $townC };
let roadDH = create Road { distance: 8, from: $townD, to: $townH };
let roadAE = create Road { distance: 4, from: $townA, to: $townE };
let roadED = create Road { distance: 2, from: $townE, to: $townD };
let roadEF = create Road { distance: 4, from: $townE, to: $townF };
let roadFG = create Road { distance: 3, from: $townF, to: $townG };
let roadGH = create Road { distance: 10, from: $townG, to: $townH };
let roadDG = create Road { distance: 8, from: $townD, to: $townG };
```

Now we need to define our weight calculator operator:

```
CREATE WEIGHT CALCULATOR shortestRoute {
    minimum:    0,
    default:    0, 
    edges: {
        ()-[r:Road]->(): r.distance
    }
};
```

Objectivity/DB is unique from other graph databases because it allows you to define multiple weight calculators that can calculate an edge weight on an attribute of an edge or on a variety of simple or complex factors across the same dataset. You do not need to embed the weight as an attribute in the data.

And finally our query:

```
MATCH m = LIGHTEST shortestRoute 
           ((:Town {name == 'TownA'})-[*]->(:Town {name == 'TownH'})) 
RETURN m;
```

Running this query gives us the following results:

```
DO> MATCH m = LIGHTEST  shortestRoute ((:Town {name == 'TownA'})-[*]->(:Town {name == 'TownH'})) RETURN m;

{
  _Projection
  {
    m:WALK
    {
      length:2,
      weight:11.0000,     <-----This is the weight of the shortest path.
      edges:
      {
        EDGE
        {
          weight:3.00000,
          from:3-3-1-4,           <--- This is the object id of TownA
          fromClass:'Town',
          attribute:'to',
          edgeData:3-3-1-35,
          edgeDataClass:'Road',
          to:3-3-1-10,             <--- This is the object id of TownD
          toClass:'Town'
        },
        EDGE
        {
          weight:8.00000,
          from:3-3-1-10,             <--- This is the object id of TownD
          fromClass:'Town',
          attribute:'to',
          edgeData:3-3-1-41,
          edgeDataClass:'Road',
          to:3-3-1-18,             <--- This is the object id of TownH
          toClass:'Town'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, we can find the k shortest paths. This is a little harder because with Objectivity's DO query language we have to make a guess as to the maximum weight for the heaviest path and use that in the MAX WEIGHT clause. In my case I am using 25.0 as the weight value greater than any path-weight in the graph.

The query is as follows:

```
MATCH m = MAX WEIGHT 25.0 routeDistance 
          ((:Town {name == 'TownA'})-[*]->(:Town {name == 'TownH'})) 
          order by weight(m) asc take 3 
          RETURN m
```

We can modify the query slightly and only return the weights:

```
MATCH m = MAX WEIGHT 25.0 routeDistance 
          ((:Town {name == 'TownA'})-[*]->(:Town {name == 'TownH'})) 
          order by weight(m) asc take 3 
          RETURN weight(m);

{
  _Projection
  {
    weight(m):11.0000
  },
  _Projection
  {
    weight(m):14.0000
  },
  _Projection
  {
    weight(m):19.0000
  }
}
```