# Is graph-database right to identify a business route?

Tags: graph-databases, tinkerpop3

I have a business logic to identify the cost effective `route` that benefits business. The `route` here means, technically, an api/connectivity (service-provider) the application should connect to fulfil the transaction, and the benefit here is the price the business gets in fulfilling the transaction.

A `route` has to be identified based on different parameters - some are, value of the transaction, the connectivity to the service-provider to perform the transaction, the priority flag set on service-provider, transaction counters for service-providers, the client who performs the transaction, the type of transaction performed, the properties present in the transaction that a service-provider expects, the service-providers charges (the lowest), and others.

As of now these properties are squeezed into relational database, the routes are queried with a mid-complex query. I am interested to see if `graph database` like `Apache Tinkerpop` is right for such usecases. I already have used a `graphdb` for a kind-of product recommendation engine based on customer relationships. One thing to note is, the business continues to change the routes anytime based on the traffic & demand.

I will add details if required.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124059/weighted-graph-database-recommedations/66289612#66289612  and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64214453/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-add-connected-meta-data-to-an-edge-using-a-graph-da/66280914#66280914

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd say this is a typical graph database use case.

What you need is a shortest path algorithm to help you find the most cost effective path for businesses. Taking the parameters you mentioned in the question into consideration, you might need to use them as vertices, edges (relationships), or properties on vertex/edge in a graph model.

Now I am trying to provide a model based on your description and my understanding. It's by no means a complete (or correct) model since I am sure there's much info missing here. Just a sample for your reference.

Typically in a property graph model there will be three concepts:

- Vertex
- Edge/Relationship
- Properties for a vertex or an edge

Based on the information you provided, the graph model can have:

- Vertices - service-provider, with priority, charges and transaction counters as its properties；the client
- Edges - Transaction, with value of the transaction as its property

You can come up with something like this:

[The basic unit of the graph model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fWYM.png)

Finally, if your data set is not too large, say under 1 billion (vertices and edges together), most graph databases can handle that. As to their performance, if your data can be placed in single node (host), then there's not much difference.